# The TextViews populated in my GridView appear blank

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using a Gridview to show a list of skills. The code runs fine, even populates exact number of items according to my array. However, the **`TextView`** that should display the item names is blank.

This is the code for my gridview adapter

**SkillsAdapter.java**

```
public class SkillsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private final String[] skillValues;

        public SkillsAdapter(Context context, String[] skillValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.skillValues = skillValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                // get layout from mobile.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skills_single_item, null);

                // set value into textview
                textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.single_label);
                textView.setText(skillValues[position]);


            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return skillValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

This is the code for my layout file **skills_single_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The array is not null. The error occurs somewhere around here

```
// set value into textview
textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.single_label);
textView.setText(skillValues[position]);
```

Comment: skillValues is arraylist? so you have to retrieve data live skillValues.get(position).toString()

Comment: set text of textview out of the if else

Comment: You are setting value in "if", what about else case ?? Place that setText line after your if-else.

Comment: move setText outside the if else statement

Comment: It's not an arraylist just a regular array. Setting the text outside the if statement also didn't work.

Comment: textview textcolor problem?

Comment: Thanks it was a textcolor problem

Comment: welcome. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout Item XML with this your I used your Adapter class its work fine at  my side

it may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set test in your text view out of if condition like:

```
if (convertView == null) {

                // get layout from mobile.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skills_single_item, null);

                // set value into textview
                textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.single_label);



            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }
textView.setText(skillValues[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move following line out of if-else blocks

```
textView.setText(skillValues[position]);
```

Like

```
  if (convertView == null) {
     // get layout from mobile.xml
     gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skills_single_item, null); 
     textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.single_label);
  } else {
       gridView = (View) convertView;
  }

  // set value into textview
  textView.setText(skillValues[position]);
```

I recommend you to read android [ViewHolder](https://www.ricston.com/blog/optimising-listview-viewholder-pattern/) pattern.